# merging multiple rows into a single row

Tags: r

i have multiple entries for each "customerID" and each entry has a order number, order type and order time in the column "Number", "type", "time". I want to combine multiple rows into a single row according to the order number "Number". for each customer, order time and order number is in increasing order.

```
xxx <- data.frame(CustomerID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5), Number = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,4,1), type = c("ball", "pen", "compass", "ball", "eraser", "ball", "watch", "pen", "ball", "scale", "ball"), time = c(0.58, 1.23, 2.34, 2.11, 4.57, 0.58, 1.02, 3.23, 4.32, 5.45, 0.23) )
```

the expected output is

````
customerID  Number_1   Number_2 Number_3 Number_4   type_1   Type_2   type_3                                                                      
1                1           2         3       NA     ball     pen    compass
2                 1          2         NA      NA     ball     eraser  NA
3                1          NA         NA      NA     ball     NA      NA
time_1   time_2 time_3 time_4
```0.58    1.23    2.34    2.11
2.11       4.57     NA     NA
0.58       NA        NA    NA\
````

Comment: This might help: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/#from-long-to-wide-1

Comment: Do you want them grouped by customer ID or Number? The final output you've provided doesn't have them grouped by number. It has all of the numbers in one row. In addition to the link above you could also try [reshape](http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/reshape-in-r-from-wide-to-long-from-long-to-wide/)

Comment: If you don't need the `Number_x` columns, then `reshape(xxx,idvar="CustomerID",timevar="Number",direction="wide")` seems to give what you're asking for.

Comment: I need the column "number"

Comment: the solution mentioned earlier worked perfectly for the desired output. I am not sure why the solution was deleted.

Comment: I did not delete the solution.

Comment: It was turning the data into wide format. But that is not what the "desired output" shows (the "desired output", if it really is what is wanted, loses lots of information. It is not a transformation of the data, but a form of summary of the categories). It is possible that Akrun's solution was the correct one and that the OP did not write the "desired output" properly

Comment: Kindly excuse me for my mistakes, I am new to R and Stack overflow.The desired output is a single row for each customerID with multiple columns for orderNumber, OrderType and OrderTime.

Comment: @akrun I have not shown those in the example, but they are suppose to be present in actual data set. I think my presentation of the output has caused confusions. There should be a row for every customerID i.e. 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: @akrun can you share that version with me again??

Comment: Error Message1: Values in `Number` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(Number = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(Number = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(Number = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates

Comment: cells that should to contains value is showing <dbl> and the cells that should contain NA is showing <NULL>.

Comment: I am actually using the original data set and not the example I posted.

Comment: xxx %>%  
  group_by(customerID) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(Number, type, time), names_from =  Number). I used this code to get almost the right answer. the only problem is that it is not grouping CustomerID together.

Comment: @AashayMehta Can you try `xxx %>% group_by(CustomerID, Number) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(values_from = c(Number, type, time), names_from =  Number)`

Comment: It is possible that your original datasets have some duplicate rows for CustomerID and Number

Comment: No, there is no duplicated rows for customerID and Number. Only Duplicated rows for CustomerID.

Comment: WORKED, WORKED, WORKED!!!!!! Thank a lot @akrun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
xxx %>%
   pivot_wider(values_from = c(Number, type, time), names_from =  Number)
# A tibble: 5 x 13
#  CustomerID Number_1 Number_2 Number_3 Number_4 type_1 type_2 type_3  type_4 time_1 time_2 time_3 time_4
#       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>   <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1          1        1        2        3       NA ball   pen    compass <NA>    0.580   1.23   2.34  NA   
#2          2        1        2       NA       NA ball   eraser <NA>    <NA>    2.11    4.57  NA     NA   
#3          3        1       NA       NA       NA ball   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    0.580  NA     NA     NA   
#4          4        1        2        3        4 watch  pen    ball    scale   1.02    3.23   4.32   5.45
#5          5        1       NA       NA       NA ball   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    0.23   NA     NA     NA
```

---

If there are duplicates for 'CustomerID' and 'Number', create a sequence column grouped by these columns and then do the `pivot_wider`

```
xxx %>% 
  group_by(CustomerID, Number) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(Number, type, time), names_from =  Number)
```

Comment: @AashayMehta. It is from `tidyr`

Comment: Do you have a recent version of `tidyr`? `tidyr::pivot_wider()` is a new function improving `tidyr::spread()`

Comment: it is giving an output in the form of Column - type.1(customerID) type.2(customerID) type.3(customerID) ........ for all the customerID and the continuing  time.1  time.2  
  time.3   time.4.... for all the customerID. Whereas, the output i expect is, in terms of coumn - CustomerID Number_1 Number_2 Number_3 .... type_1 type_2 type_3 ..... time_1 time_2 time_3 ....

Comment: @AashayMehta. Do you need only a single row output for multiple rows?  I am confused

Comment: Yes, single row output for multiple rows

Comment: @AashayMehta. Have you loaded `library(data.table)`

Comment: @akrun the function return a single row and 34 columns. I expect 1 row per customer with number of column = customerID + order number (1,2,3...n) + order type(ball, pen, watch....m ) + time (time of order_no_1, order_number_2...., q)

Comment: @akrun I want to remove the time values of "Cap" and retain the time value of the adjacent cell.

Comment: @AashayMehta. In that case, you can subset the `time` columns with `grep` (more dynamic. `nm1 <- grep("^time\\d+$", names(report), value = TRUE); report[nm1] <- t(apply(report[nm1], 1, function(x) {
               i1 <- x == 'cap'
              c(x[!i1], rep(NA, sum(i1, na.rm = TRUE)))}))`

Comment: @akrun should i write this code after executing the first code??

Comment: @AashayMehta Yes, you can do that